# Notepad++ "Compress whitespace" effect

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking for a mechanism within notepad++ to replace runs of consecutive whitespace with a single space, like the "Compress whitespace" command in notepad2.

Essentially, in regex form:

```
s/\s+/ /g
```

I know I can do it with the find-replace form, but I would prefer soemthing that I can bind to a keyboard sequence.

#### EDIT

Find and replace cannot be recorded as a macro in some versions of Notepad++. Update to the latest if you have trouble.

Comment: Wouldn't \s also match end of line characters?  I'd think you'd want to find ` +` (space plus) and replace with ` ` (space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to set this regex up as a macro and then bind the macro to a shortcut.

> Settings > Shortcut mapper... > Macros

Comment: For whatever reason, I can't save the act of using the find-replace dialog as a macro.

Comment: @tylerl  when I do start recording, then do a find/replace of abc to xyz, then stop recording.  then write in abc , then click macro..playback, it plays it back. so it does record. and  I see an option to the current macro

Comment: @barlop - Doesn't work here. I do *start recording*, then *find-replace*, then *stop-recording* -- my macro isn't saved. It's as if I hadn't done a find-replace. The *Playback* option is grayed out.

Comment: @barlop - Updated notepad++ to the latest version, and it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Edit > Blank Operations > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL

Not sure if that's a default feature or plugin, but there's always a million plugins to do anything else.
The TextFX Plugin is worth a look as well.

Comment: Wonder how to do it without removing EOL but still compress space (without doing regex find ` +` (space plus) and replace with ` ` (space)?